# Javascript top level object - window doesn't seem to cut it

Tags: javascript

Hey JS gurus... I am juggling w/ some crazy weird google map stuff. I need to store 2 numbers (lat/long), click on a pin, and on the new page, use these numbers.

So I tried to store these in the good ole' window:

window.lat = ...;
window.lng = ...;

however, the window after the click on the map is not the same window that holds our lat, lng.

So the question is: does our 'new' window hold a reference to the one that has out lat/lng? I tried window.top, window.parent, window.frames, it's all equal to window...

Alternatively, where can I store those values to be able to restore them later?

Comment: This is very vague. Please include more source code. Just two lines that aren't full expressions aren't reliable.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot persist Javascript variables across pages.

Instead, you should use a cookie.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at cookies/sessions to hold values over different pages:

JavaScript Cookies: (note i've never actually used these, but presume this info is up to date)
http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Sessions: (PHP as example, but all server-side languages support sessions)
http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php

Answer (score 0):

Either you have to use **Cookie** or you should pass these numbers as **URL variables**.
Every time you load the Window the complete **DOM** be written again, that's why your variables no more exist after page reload.